# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_privacy' has no attribute 'DPQuery'

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, attributeerror, tensorflow-federated, federated-learning

I am new to machine learning and was trying out the "federated learning for image classification" code by Tensorflow (https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_learning_for_image_classification). I ran the code on Google Colab and did not modify anything.

```
#@test {"skip": true}

# tensorflow_federated_nightly also bring in tf_nightly, which
# can causes a duplicate tensorboard install, leading to errors.
!pip uninstall --yes tensorboard tb-nightly

!pip install --quiet --upgrade tensorflow-federated-nightly
!pip install --quiet --upgrade nest-asyncio
!pip install --quiet --upgrade tb-nightly  # or tensorboard, but not both

import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()

%load_ext tensorboard
```

The above works well. (no errors)
But when it comes to the below:

```
import collections

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_federated as tff

np.random.seed(0)

tff.federated_computation(lambda: 'Hello, World!')()
```

I got an error on the `import tensorflow_federated as tff` line:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_privacy' has no attribute 'DPQuery'
```

I've searched for solutions like `pip install -U TensorFlow-privacy` but none works.

Please help.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a solution to your problem but afaik no tutorial other than the tff optimizers require tff nightly, so you can just use stable tff releases.

```
!pip install --quiet --upgrade tensorflow-federated
!pip install --quiet --upgrade nest-asyncio

import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
```

this one should install tff 0.19

Comment: Thank you! It worked! Is it possible for you to answer a follow-up question? While I was running the pip install codes, I got error message `ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
spacy 2.2.4 requires tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.38.0, but you have tqdm 4.28.1 which is incompatible.
pymc3 3.11.2 requires cachetools>=4.2.1, but you have cachetools 3.1.1 which is incompatible...`. It doesn't seem to affect the installations, but I'm curious about solving this error. Thanks!

Comment: i do get the same errors but I dont know how to solve it. so far these errors caused no problems.